# Axios Delete operation on React-bootstrap-table displaying [object%20Object] on the browser's console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to perform an axios delete operation on a react-bootstrap-table, but I am getting this error on the console

```
  DELETE http://localhost:9000/api/terminals/[object%20Object]
  Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
```

These are the codes

const

```
  const apiUrl = 'api/terminals';
```

UseState and UseEffect

```
     const [data, setData] = useState([]);

       useEffect(() => {
       getData();
       }, []);

      const getData = () => {
     axios(apiUrl).then(res => {
     setData(res.data);
    });
    };
```

Axios delete

```
        const handleDelete = rowId => {
        axios.delete(`${apiUrl}/${rowId}`).then(() => setData(data));
        };
```

Modal Content

```
     const ModalContent = () => {
          return (
             <>
      <Modal show={showModal} onHide={handleClose}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Confirm delete operation</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>Are you sure you want to delete this Terminal? 
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={id => handleDelete(id)}>Confirm</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
   </>
   );
  };
```

main jsx with bootstrap Table

```
  <>
  <BootstrapTable
    keyField="id"
    data={data}
    columns={columns}
    striped
    hover
    condensed
    pagination={paginationFactory()}
    cellEdit={cellEdit}
    filter={filterFactory()}
    noDataIndication="Table is Empty"
   
    />
    {showModal ? <ModalContent /> : null}
  </>
```

Comment: So the issue you have here is that the modal does not know which id you want to delete. You will have to rethink how you want the delete modal to work. One quick solution is to use a state of the id you want to delete that is passed down as a prop to the modal. However this also comes with its own issues

Answer (score 0):

You use an object instead of a string in the delete url.
Normally you get an event from a onClick and not the id.
If you get the id from somewhere else in the code that you do not show the you could try this.

```js
<Button variant="primary" onClick={() => handleDelete(id)}>
   Confirm
</Button>
```

Comment: When I try your formular, I get "cannot find name 'id'"

Comment: Where in the code do you have access to the rowId needed in the delete function?

Comment: rowId is a clickevent, I thought I would get the data's rowId when I pass it in an arrow function

Comment: In your code you get the event from the click. If you share more of the code that you labeld as jsx I might be able to guide you more

Comment: Okay.. I have added more codes to guide you. Thanks